# How do I completely remove MySQL from macOS Mojave?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and have only started learning. I've recently installed MySQL on macOS Mojave but found it difficult to use for some reason (given that I'm new to the tool and language). Wanted to remove it completely from the system. Please let me know how to wipe it out completely (including hidden/registry files). Alternatively, I would also like to install another SQL RDBMS so please also recommend something for a starter.

Advice on whether this is the right decision to remove MySQL will also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Which of the ways to install it did you use? What `sudo find / 2>/dev/null | grep -i mysql` writes?

Comment: Downloaded the dmg file from [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) and went through the installation process.

Comment: You might want to run the command I hinted, edit in your question the whole output (take care with sensitive information), then discuss next steps.

Comment: This woulda belonged in [apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com) a little more than here, but don't re post over there. If a worthwhile thing to do, it'll get moved by a site moderator.

Comment: Hi john, apologies. Have I posted something wrong or sensitive?

Comment: No, I mean watch what you share if you share the `find` command output.

Comment: So as of now no issue? Because I still didn't quite understand. Sorry for any incompetence

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, no.

Comment: Is there any breach of information at my end? Also please recommend an alternative to MySQL if possible?

Comment: “Is there any breach of information at my end?” Nothing am aware of. “[...] alternative to [...]” [Software recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: [Derived question at softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69103/59507)